# Determining if date is between start/end dates, and averaging days since start

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a long list of processes that all have start and end dates. I would like to be able to find how many processes, that have run for more than a day, are running on a given date, and the average time since start. In the end I want to make a plot showing the average process time over time. What I am having trouble with is not identifying which processes are running on a give date, but averaging the time since start for all processes that running on a given date.

Example Date ('Raw' sheet):
[image: ![enter image description here]

Desired Results ('Data' sheet):
[image: ![enter image description here]

To get the number of processes running on a given day, I used the following:

```
=COUNTIFS(raw!B:B, "<" & data!A2, raw!C:C, ">" & data!A2) + COUNTIFS(raw!B:B, "<" & data!A2, raw!C:C, "=" & "")
```

**Long description of above tables.:**
If I have a process that started on 1-1-20, and only that process is running on 1-1-20, then the 'Average Days Since Process Start' is 0 as it has been running less then a day. On 2-1-20, if still that is the only process running, then the 'Average Days Since Process Start' is 1 since that single process has been running for 1 day.

If I start a new process on 4-1-20, though there are two processes running yet the process with less than 1 day of operation is not be counted.  So the average will be 3/1=3.  Then on 5-1-20 the 'Average Days Since Process Start' is 2.5 as the first process has been running 4 days, and the second 1 day. (1+4)/2 = 2.5

If I start yet another process on 10-1-20, but stopped the first process on 9-1-20, then on 11-1-20 the 'Average Days Since Process Start' is 4, as the second process has been running for 7 days, and the third process for 1. (1+7)/2 = 4

Comment: @MátéJuhász stuck with 2016 at work.

Comment: It's unusual for a question to get three up-votes then be closed. I will vote to re-open it.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question, well provided with test data and results. Although there appears to be a slight inconsistency between the screenshots and the text (should a process started on the current day be counted or not?) I think it should stand.

Comment: I do not understand why it was closed. @TomSharpe the clarification text was a simplified scenario to give more clarity. I will edit the test date to match the clarification text as I believe the clarification text does more to explain what it is that I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @AnilGoyal updated to match. It is not 0.5 because 1 process has been running for 1 day. The average should be of the day since each process has started.

Comment: So I cleaned up the question. How do I get this reopened?

Comment: @AnilGoyal P001 started on 1-1-20, so on 4-1-20 it has been running for 3 days. P002 was started on 4-1-2020 it has been running > a day, so it not counted in the average. So in the end one process has been running for 3 days so the average is 3 days. I understand that normally you would assume that P002 would count toward the average on 4-1-20, but this just boils down to the criteria I have in my report.

Comment: @AnilGoyal I am only considering processes that have run for a full day. I will update the post to make that clearer.

Comment: @AnilGoyal correct. Processes last longer than a days, but sometimes we have failed starts which are included in the report. That is why processes < 1 days are irrelevant. Why I like your power query solution, I am afraid to use it because I am 100% sure everyone has power query; I work for a large corp, and because of "security", etc. we are behind the curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only get the same answers as OP if I use a formula like this to count the number of active processes at a particular date:

```
=COUNTIFS(B$2:B$10,"<"&F2,C$2:C$10,">="&F2)
```

This gives one less than the number of processes shown in the question because a process is not included if it starts on the current date. This seems inconsistent with the description given in the 'Clarification' section of the question.

I can then sum up the number of days like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((F2-B$2:B$10)*(B$2:B$10<=F2)*(C$2:C$10>=F2))
```

and divide one by the other to get the average days per process. Note the <= and >= in the above formula.

```
    =IFERROR(H2/G2,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution in this case is -

Data used-

[image]

**Step-1** select `raw` table then Data (Menu) > Get & Transform (from table)

**Step-2** change the data-type of dates column to `number`

**Step-3** Create a custom column as

[image]

calculation used-

```
={[Start]..[End]}
```

**Step-4** Expand dates by right clicking the column, you'll get an output like this

[image]

**Step[-5** change data-type of this new column to dates

**Step-6** Delete two start and end columns (these aren't needed now)

**Step-7** Group-by Process column by right clicking it.. (output will be like the following screenshot)

[image]

**Step-8** add another custom column with following calculation

[image]

```
Table.AddIndexColumn([Count],"Index",0)
```

**Step-9** remove other columns by right clicking new column

**Step-10**  expand this column to get an output like this

[image]

**Step-11** remove process column

**Step-12** Group-by again with following settings

[image]

You'll get desired output like this

[image]

All query steps can be re-checked with this screenshot

[image]

Good Luck.  Formatted final output

[image]

**PS** I would've solved first part in powerquery also.  If you need the steps do tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution:

The layout is little different from yours, but you can after create your own layout.

1. In `ROWS 9` there are the dates.
2. In `Column A` there are the processes
3. The row of single process there are the number of the days that the
   process is running.
4. `Row(15) Days` there are the days to start from zero.
5. `Row(16)Processes` active there are the numbers of processes active in that day. In my
   example the formula, in cells B16, is `COUNTIF(B10:B14,">" & 0)`.
6. Row(17) AVERAGE: there are the everages. The formula is, in cells(B17),
   `IF.ERROR(B15/SUMM(B10:B14),0)`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the offered solution, but I need this to work in the format that I provided as it need to match the format coming from an exported file.